# Batch remove characters from filename without altering extension

Tags: batch-file

The batch code below removes the character 'x' from filenames, but also remove the 'x' in the extension '.docx'  .  How to prevent the code from renaming the extension ?

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *x*.docx') do (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!fname:x=!"
    ren "!fname!" "!nname!"
    endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the name from the extension using `%%~na` and `%%~xa` then do the replace on the name only, then simply join the new name with the extension.

You do not need the dir cmd either. if your files are in the root of `D:\test` then run this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in ("D:\test\*x*.docx" ) do (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    set "xonly=%%~xa"
    set "nonly=%%~dpna"
    set "nonly=!nonly:x=!"
    ren "!fname!" "!nonly!!xonly!"
)
```

If your files are in subdirectories inside of `D:\test` then do a search recursively:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for "D:\Test" /R %%a in (*x*.docx) do (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    set "xonly=%%~xa"
    set "nonly=%%~dpna"
    set "nonly=!nonly:x=!"
    ren "!fname!" "!nonly!!xonly!"
)
```

Note that `%%~a` would be  drive and file, so we make sure we set `!nonly!` as drive, path and name, in other words `%%~dpna`

For more help on variable substitution, open `cmd.exe` and run `for /?`

Answer (score -2):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d *x*.docx') do (
    set "fname=%%~na"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "nname=!fname:x=!"
    ren "%%a" "!nname!%%~xa"
    endlocal
)
```

Execute the CMD from the same folder as the files to be renamed.

Comment: Worked Perfectly now , when i placed in the same folder as the files. Thanks again sir.  God Bless !